# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233 - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I have a subdomain folder running on php 7. Globally my php version is 5.6 actually. When i run my project, i get a 500 internal error. Checking my error_log, i see this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/invoice/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 358

I tried to install this command `composer require symfony/polyfill-icon` in my subfolder (under the subdomain which is running on php 7) but then this is the result in the terminal

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController" was found in both "/home/laravel/public_html/myproject/app/Http/Controllers/mNotify/Auth/RegisterController.php" and "/home/laravel/public_html/myproject/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php", the first will be used.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/laravel/public_html/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
```

When i look in the `vendor file` in my subfolder under the subdomain, the 
`Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv` is installed there but when i test from the terminal using `php --ir iconv`, it get `Extension iconv is not present`.

What is happening?

Comment: Your PHP lacks the `iconv` extension. Fixing it depends how your PHP was installed in the first place.

Comment: @ceejayoz but i thought i could be fixed using this command `composer require symfony/polyfill-icon`

Comment: As for your parse error, that's due to you running PHP 7 code in PHP 5. (Line 233 says ...`$arguments[1] ?? null`, and `??` wasn't in PHP <7.)

Comment: @cHao, yes that was why i updated the php version to 7 in sub-domain but then i don't know why it is still given that error. Composer is globally installed anyway. Could it be so because of that, composer is using php 5 (which is the global version)

Comment: @LearnLaravel: Probably is. If you just say `composer do something`, it'll run under the interpreter that's listed in the shebang line. You might be able to say `name_of_php7 $(which composer) do something` instead.

Comment: @cHao  Is there any work around for this issue? because i need to get iconv

Comment: As mentioned, how to install iconv depends in large part on how PHP 7 was installed (and to some degree also on whether your system meets the requirements, but any modern *nix should). It might be as simple as editing a config file to load the extension, or it might require installing libiconv and rebuilding. To just load up the polyfill and use it (assuming you have the required other stuff), check my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

check if mod php < 7.0 has enabled to disabled it.
and enable mod php 7 or 7.1